# How do I forward fill line items data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, fillna, forward-fill

I have an exported sheet of order line items and that has a master order number in column A but the order data is only completely filled on the first line item.

The blank cells are creating an issue when I try to work with the data.

What is the best way to fill out the blank cells with the data from the first line item?

I've tried to merge rows but I am only trying to merge if the cells are empty and of the same order number.

I came up with an idea:

1. `=if($A3=$A2,if(ISBLANK(C2),"",C2),"FALSE")`
2. Then filter by blank cells and copy and paste.

Is this the best way?

Input:

| Name | Email | Shipping Method | Lineitem quantity | Lineitem price | Lineitem sku | Shipping Address1 | Shipping Address2 | Shipping City | Shipping Zip | Shipping Province |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 0 | XXXXSKU | XXXXXX Avenue | Apt #220 | Venice | 90291 | CA |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com |  | 1 | 24.95 | XXXXLO01 |  |  |  |  |  |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com |  | 2 | 44.95 | PRO20LL |  |  |  |  |  |
| 985285 | email2@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 85.4 | PRO20LL02 | XXXXXX Ave |  | Norwell | 2889 | RI |
| 985288 | email3@gmail.com | Priority Shipping (2-3 days) | 1 | 44.95 | PRO20LL | XXXXXX Parkway |  | Minneapolis | 55408 | MA |
| 985287 | email4@gmail.com | Priority Shipping (2-3 days) | 1 | 44.95 | PRO20LL | XXX Street | Apt #4 | Minneapolis | 55102 | MN |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 35.96 | XXXXX-01 | XXXXX Road |  | Norwell | 2061 | MA |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com |  | 1 | 40.46 | PRO20LL |  |  |  |  |  |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com |  | 1 | 35.96 | XXXX_SK01 |  |  |  |  |  |

Ideal output:

| Name | Email | Shipping Method | Lineitem quantity | Lineitem price | Lineitem sku | Shipping Address1 | Shipping Address2 | Shipping City | Shipping Zip | Shipping Province |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 0 | XXXXSKU | XXXXXX Avenue | Apt #220 | Venice | 90291 | CA |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 24.95 | XXXXLO01 | XXXXXX Avenue | Apt #220 | Venice | 90291 | CA |
| 985292 | email1@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 2 | 44.95 | PRO20LL | XXXXXX Avenue | Apt #220 | Venice | 90291 | CA |
| 985285 | email2@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 85.4 | PRO20LL02 | XXXXXX Ave |  | Norwell | 2889 | RI |
| 985288 | email3@gmail.com | Priority Shipping (2-3 days) | 1 | 44.95 | PRO20LL | XXXXXX Parkway |  | Minneapolis | 55408 | MA |
| 985287 | email4@gmail.com | Priority Shipping (2-3 days) | 1 | 44.95 | PRO20LL | XXX Street | Apt #4 | Minneapolis | 55102 | MN |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 35.96 | XXXXX-01 | XXXXX Road |  | Norwell | 2061 | MA |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 40.46 | PRO20LL | XXXXX Road |  | Norwell | 2061 | MA |
| 985250 | email5@gmail.com | Expedited Plus Shipping (3-4 days) | 1 | 35.96 | XXXX_SK01 | XXXXX Road |  | Norwell | 2061 | MA |

Comment: Consider providing input and expected output as **plain text table** in the question. [Click here](//webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855) to create a table easily, which are **easy to copy/paste**.  Avoid sharing [links like spreadsheets](//meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455), which make the question useless for others or [images](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551), which are hard to copy. Also, note that [your email address can also be accessed by the public](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/394304), if you share Google files.

Comment: Hi, can you provide us the expected output ?

Comment: @TheMaster thank you for pointing me in the right direction, I've uploaded a plain text table.

Comment: @AntoineF thank you, I provided the expected output in a plain text table. Please let me know if you need me to clarify further. I appreciate the help.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- This is called forward fill and can be accomplished using [`SCAN`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12569094).  Using `SCAN`, iterate through each `Name`(col A) and to get a  comparator function to compare each  item(`c`) to the previous accumulated one(`a`)
- Extend each col A inside `SCAN` using `OFFSET` to the entire 10 columns(`ce`)
- Compare  current Col A `Name` with the `a`ccumulator's `Name` and if `c`urrent value is empty, put the `a`ccumulator, else the  extended  current value `ce`

Assuming the table is in A1:K10, in A15,

```
=SCAN(
  A1,A2:A10,
  LAMBDA(a,c,
    LET(
      cols,10,
      ce,OFFSET(c,0,0,1,cols),
      ARRAYFORMULA(
        IF(
          (ce="")*((c=INDEX(a,1,1))),a,ce
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I will play around with this and read the docs re: these functions.